# Inheritance referring instance variables

Tags: java

```
class A{

int x= 30;
void printA(){
Sysout(x);
}
}

class B extends A{
int x= 40;
}

class MyMain(){
public static void main(String args[]){

B obj = new B();
obj.printA(){
}
}
```

B is the child class of A.
Why the output is coming t be 30?? It should b 40? Object of B should have value of x as 40. And sysout(x) means this.x

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the print that refers to A.x and not to B.x. You should try to override printA in B

Comment: but it is this.x, this refers to current object!

Comment: of course, B does not override printA so the compiler call A.printA

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are calling the method using B, it is executing method from A as it have access. And you are using the variable from class A in that method.

> And sysout(x) means this.x

Yes, in your case, this means A as you not overridden that method.